Can I use parameters also for table and columns name?
Is this below Postgresql query valid?
INSERT INTO "$1" ("$2", "id", "created_by", "name")
VALUES ($3, $4, $5)
RETURNING *

In other words: can I use parameters also for table and columns name?

Simple answer is - you can not use parameters as table or column name. Use dynamic SQL.

An example of dynamic SQL?

You may look here. Dynamic SQL can be used in PL/pgSQL only.

Or if you are not running the query directly, you build it in whatever client library you are using.

How come you don't know the table and column names? Your query will fail anyway, you mention 4 columns and you have just 3 values.
